# Touch Screen Simulator: Are there any windows simulator to test application in touch screen environment

Tags: windows, screen, touch, simulator

I want to test my application in touch screen environment. My application is a web site build in asp.net(.net framework 3.5) and flash.
I want to test my application with the simulator with Windows XP/Vista/7.

Please let me know is there any simulator released by Microsoft or any third party where I can test my application.

Thanks
Vinay Pandey

Answer (score 10):

You can use Windows 8 and Visual studio 2012 express and there is Windows Simulator when you run Windows store (aka Metro) applications trough VS. But you can run Simulator without VS and run any installed windows app trough it.

Simulator is located in :

```
c:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Simulator\11.0\Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.exe
```

or

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Simulator\11.0\Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.exe
```

Comment: If the application shows up, loads for a while than exits, try to run it from the command line with your windows user / pass (in the path change version to your visual studio version, i.e. 11.0, 12.0 or 15.0):

`C:\Windows\System32\runas.exe /user:youremailaddress@example.com "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\Windows Simulator\11.0\Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.exe"`
[source](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/32193/unable-to-launch-windows-simulator-on-machine-with.html)

Answer (score 3):

I have had considerable luck with the free version of [SplashTop](http://www.splashtop.com/) and an Android tablet, which can be had quite cheaply. The desktop streamer works well in a LAN.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Microsoft Surface SDK.  It contains a simulator that can simulate a system that only has touch capabilities (ie. Microsoft Surface).  It doesn't seem to want to install on 64 bit Win 7 so I couldn't test it.

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody is still looking for that in 2018(like I do), it is possible to use Microsoft Remote Desktop + iPad(or probably any Android tablet - haven't tried) with free "RD Client" app. The downside is that you'll be logged out from your PC session when connected from iPad.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com/

Or buy a cheap tablet with Win7/XP.

Comment: "http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com/" This simulator can be install on my Windows XP machine.

Comment: Are you asking me? I am not sure.

Comment: What I want is need a simulator which takes input as from touch screen

Comment: Yes. I tried this but this is simulator which takes input from multiple mikes.What I want is need is a simulator which takes input as from touch screen. Don't need any mouse, keyboard or mike.

Comment: Not aware of such simulator. But does your website actually have any touch screen specific functionality (like swiping, which is only really supported on mobile browsers like Android and Mobile Safari)?

Comment: No, It does not include such kind of functionality.

Comment: Well then the browsers on a touch enabled Windows XP/7 will do nothing different then on a normal Windows XP/7. Just consider if it is worth the hassle of testing your site on a touch enabled Windows device and if it is, just get a touch enabled device for testing then. You also have an option to test on Android simulator, which is available for Windows.