# How do you test touch-enabled apps on a non-touch Windows?

Tags: windows, delphi, touch

There is no canonical answer to this question (links below.)

I have a desktop Windows app developed using a non-Visual Studio environment (Delphi) and run Windows 7 in a VM, but otherwise standard desktop. I'd like to test some touch features, and so would like to mimic touch on desktop Windows. How do you do this?

Answers gives in other links:

- [Use the Surface 2 SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3766662/touch-screen-simulator-are-there-any-windows-simulator-to-test-application-in-t). Installs only if you have VS2010. (I have VS2013 installed currently.)
- [Inject touch events via a touch injection API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507568/is-there-a-way-to-simulate-touch-events-in-windows-8?rq=1). Writing your own touch simulator seems a little surprising, and in addition this reportedly only works on Windows 8.
- [Use the Windows Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547542/windows-8-store-app-development-without-touch-screen). With my Visual Studio 2013 installation, there are DLL files present but no simulator. Googling shows no results for how to install it, or what it is a prerequisite for or installed with, in order to install it by installing something else. It may (?) also work only with Windows Store apps, it's hard to tell.

There are a number of other replies which rely on using Visual Studio.

So, for a **Windows 7 desktop** machine, using a **non-Visual-Studio-developed app**, how do you simulate touch?

Comment: I don't think you really can simulate MULTI touch.

Comment: What about single-touch? Use the mouse to mimic a single finger, for example? Basically, anything to get OnTouch events fired, preferably on the Windows level (since I'd like to test both FMX and VCL apps, with 'real'-ish input so far as is possible - at least coming from outside the app not inside.)

Comment: Why does it matter that the event fires at all if it's fake? Just fake the actions that the touch events will execute, like Sam suggests below, or invoke your OnTouch events directly, they are just methods like any other method. Call them yourself. What you won't be able to do is know if this makes any sense to use it. That's why people test on real devices.  User experience is impossible to simulate. You can get a Windows 8.1 or Windows 10 intel atom powered tablet for about $100 us on clearance these days. Use that for testing.

Comment: Because I want to test the full input - that is, including the messages the app gets. I can call OnTouch easily, sure, but what I am after is something that simulates input on a high enough level (above the app) that my app is not aware it is fake.

Comment: Since you don't have source code to Windows, I think the answer is, you can't.

Comment: Wellll... you can with Visual Studio. So there must be some way. I'm sure there is an emulator that converts mouse actions to touch messages, for example.

Comment: I think you just proved my point. Who makes Visual Studio? Microsoft. Do they know how to do this? Yes. Is it documented on MSDN? No.

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution consist to use a TActionList and link it with a TGestureManager. In the Form Property "Gestures" choose a gesture and Create an new action linked with the combobox.

In the TActionList choose the new created Action and put your code in it.

Now, you can simulate the gesture with a call to the action.

Comment: Thanks Sam. Unfortunately I want to simulate the OnTouch events, not gestures (though I know they use the same underlying engine; I suppose I can assume if gestures work touch will also, but I prefer to be sure.) I'd prefer to simulate on the Windows level not Delphi, too, since that way I can test both VCL and FMX apps with touch.